# I can't build my app with the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging NuGet package

Tags: ios, .net, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuget, visual-studio-mac

I'm building a .Net for Android and a .Net for iOS (formally Xamarin.Native) app. I'm trying to add Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to it. I have it working on Android and have begun to work on iOS. As soon as I add the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging NuGet package and try to run the app (without changing a single line of code) I get two warnings:

[image: The two warnings I get]

I've tried Googling the warning (and the error code) but nothing seems to come up. This package has thousands of downloads so I don't think it's the package, this very much seems to be a 'me' problem.

I get these two warnings for package versions 8.10.0.1, 8.10.0.2 & 8.10.0.3 (earlier versions won't work because they don't target .Net). I am using Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.5 (build 417).

Is there a setting I need to adjust, or a flag I need to add somewhere?